# How to display a popup - navigation with .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I’m trying to create a pop up menu with buttons in the main page, to navigate to other pages using community toolkit but I’m having trouble with it. Is it possible to do a pop up control with navigation stack using Mopups library or any other?

This is an example of what I tried to do.

In the homepage.xaml.cs file, I created a handler

`private async void OpenMenuPage(object sender, EventArgs e) { Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage()) }`

The MenuPage is a contentPage. In the cs file I did something like this

`private async void FirstPage_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { Navigation.PushAsync(new FirstPage(this)) }`

`private async void SecondPage_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(this)) }`

I’m new with this..

Thanks!

Comment: *"homepage.xaml.cs"* - Is this a `NavigationPage"? That's what you need, if you want a navigation stack.

Comment: I want to see your application class. The place where you set MainPage = ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still is wanted but I give a solution for using Popup's.

The Popup control xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup
    x:Class="MauiTest.Controls.PopupControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="True"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Color="White">

    <Grid
        Margin="10,10,10,10"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        RowDefinitions="*,*,2, *"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Button
            x:Name="Button1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Clicked="Button1_Clicked"
            Text="Menu Item 1"
            TextColor="Black" />
        <Button
            x:Name="Button2"
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Clicked="Button2_Clicked"
            Text="Menu Item 2"
            TextColor="Black" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Color="LightGray" />
        <Button
            x:Name="Button4"
            Grid.Row="3"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            Clicked="Button3_Clicked"
            Text="Menu Item 3"
            TextColor="Black" />
    </Grid>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

The Popup code behind:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;
using MauiTest.Views;

namespace MauiTest.Controls;

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PopupControl : Popup
{
    public PopupControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(new TestPage());
    }

    private void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(new TestPage());
    }

    private void Button3_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(new TestPage());
    }
}
```

And the implementation:

```cs
private async void MenuButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new PopupControl();
    var result = await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(popup);

    if (result is ContentPage contentPageResult)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(contentPageResult);
    }
}
```